# How to access values from a java.util.Map that was serialized to JSON where the key is an ebean.Model with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, playframework, ebean

I am using playframework 2.4.4 and am trying to achieve the following:

In the backend I serialize a `Map<Lagerplatz, Integer>` to JSON (`com.fasterxml.jackson`) where `Lagerplatz` is a class inheriting from `com.avaje.ebean.Model`.

In the frontend I want to deserialize the map to construct a picking list, telling the picker from which place (=Lagerplatz) to pick how many items.

The JSON I get from the serialization looks like this:

```
{
    "models.Lagerplatz@21":3,
    "models.Lagerplatz@2":6,
    "models.Lagerplatz@3":3,
    "models.Lagerplatz@47":0,
    "models.Lagerplatz@48":0,
    "models.Lagerplatz@a":3,
    "models.Lagerplatz@c":3,
    "models.Lagerplatz@15":3,
    "models.Lagerplatz@36":3,
    "models.Lagerplatz@37":3,
    "models.Lagerplatz@18":3,
    "models.Lagerplatz@38":6,
    "models.Lagerplatz@39":6,
    "models.Lagerplatz@3a":6
}
```

...so instead of serializing the whole Lagerplatz-object - for some reason only a String representation that looks like some kind of id is sent via JSON.

My question is how to access e.g. the value "3" for the key "models.Lagerplatz@21" with Javascript when all I have is a list with real Lagerplatz objects...how do I find out which Lagerplatz object refers to which "id"?

(By the way: I also serialize a java.util.List which carries the order in which the picker is supposed to pick the items and here the Lagerplatz objects get serialized "normally" so there actually is a whole Lagerplatz object in the JSON...)

This is the class Lagerplatz:

```
    package models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Min;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

@Entity
public class Lagerplatz extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Required
    @Min(0)
    private int menge;

    @Required
    @Min(1)
    private int kapazitaet;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Material material;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Kommissionierlager kommissionierlager;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Lagerplatz vorgaenger;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Lagerplatz nachfolger;


    public static Finder<Long,Lagerplatz> find = new Finder<>(Lagerplatz.class);
}
```

Comment: Hi. It looks like the "toJson" code is using some sort of Lagerplatz.toString rather than actually converting it to a json object. Would it not make more sense to fix that - get the server to send you an array of Lagerplatz objects ... something like `"{ lagerplatze":[{"id":3,"menge":12, "kapazitaet":340 ...`?

Answer (score 0):

`models.Lagerplatz@21` is actually the String representation of an ebean object as indicated by [wwkudu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2002817/wwkudu) (see his comment to my question).

`models` is the package in which the class resides, `Lagerplatz` is the object's class name and since any ebean object has a unique id (so it can be persisted to a database using ebean ORM) the part after the @ is that very id. 
For the model Lagerplatz this id is an auto generated Long value which for some reason is converted to a **hexa-decimal** value for the String representation.

So I was able to solve my problem by converting the id I get from the correctly serialized List which carries the picking order to hexa-decimal and constructing that String representation (I ommitted some code that is not necessary to understand the solution here - `kommissionierreihenfolge` is the deserialized `List<Lagerplatz>` that carries properly serialized and deserialized Lagerplatz objects, `kommissionierliste` is the `Map<Lagerplatz, Integer>` that carries the strangely serialized and deserialized Lagerplatz objects as keys and the Integers as values):

```
function setKommissionierliste(kommissionierreihenfolge, kommissionierliste) {

    var tableBodyWrapper = document.getElementById("kommissionierliste-table-body");

    for (var index in kommissionierreihenfolge) {       

        ...

        var mengeNode = document.createTextNode(kommissionierliste["models.Lagerplatz@@" + kommissionierreihenfolge[index].id.toString(16)]);

        ...
    }
}
```

Since I really only need the Lagerplatz in the `Map<Lagerplatz, Integer>` as a key to retrieve the Integer value associated with it, this solution works fine for me although it is a bit of a workaround.

As indicated by [wwkudu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2002817/wwkudu), the proper solution would be to get the server to actually send Lagerplatz objects.